# Query Firebase avoid duplicates

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm very confused trying to find the optimal way for returning a list of **MEALS** and the associated **OFFERS** in a user's results **where tasty = true**. How could I re-structure or query to achieve this?

At the moment I query OFFERS/ for every OFFER contained in a MEAL entry where tasty = true.

As this database scales it would be inefficient to pull the same offer multiple times if many meals belong to the offer surely? At the momemnt OFFER-2 is returned to the user twice for MEAL-4 and MEAL-5 offerArray=[OFFER-1,0FFER-2,OFFER-2], but that could become thousands of unnecessary queries which wouldn't be good to sort on the frontend with a loop. I would also be getting the JSON for MEAL-6 which isn't needed by the user so that is damaging performance. Is there a way to limit this so that each unique offer is returned only once, eg offerArray=[OFFER-1,OFFER-2].

```
{
"OFFERS": {
    "OFFER-1": {
        "description": "20% off today!",
        "seller": "SELLER-2",
        "includes": ["MEAL-2"]
    },
    "OFFER-2": {
        "description": "30% off all desserts today!",
        "seller": "SELLER-4",
        "includes": ["MEAL-4", "MEAL-5", "MEAL-6"]
    }
},
"SELLERS": {
    "SELLER-1": {
        "name": "Wholefoods",
        "sells": {
            "MEAL-1": true
        }
    },
    "SELLER-2": {
        "name": "Burger King",
        "offer": ["OFFER-1"],
        "sells": {
            "MEAL-2": true
        }
    },
    "SELLER-3": {
        "name": "UberEats",
        "sells": {
            "MEAL-3": true
        }
    },
    "SELLER-4": {
        "name": "Deliveroo",
        "offer": ["OFFER-2"],
        "sells": {
            "MEAL-4": true,
            "MEAL-5": true
        }
    }
},
"MEALS": {
    "MEAL-1": {
        "price": 5.95,
        "seller": "SELLER-1",
        "tasty": true
    },
    "MEAL-2": {
        "offer": ["OFFER-1"],
        "price": 4.8,
        "seller": "SELLER-2",
        "tasty": true
    },
    "MEAL-3": {
        "price": 6.0,
        "seller": "SELLER-3",
        "tasty": true
    },
    "MEAL-4": {
        "offer": ["OFFER-2"],
        "price": 5.25,
        "seller": "SELLER-4",
        "tasty": true
    },
    "MEAL-5": {
        "offer": ["OFFER-2"],
        "price": 4.6,
        "seller": "SELLER-4",
        "tasty": true
    },
    "MEAL-6": {
        "offer": ["OFFER-2"],
        "price": 5.9,
        "seller": "SELLER-4"
    },
    "MEAL-7": {
        "price": 4.26,
        "seller": "SELLER-4"
    }
}
```

}

Would appreciate any advice on the structure of the nosql.

Comment: You're going to have to load each meal in each offer from the client-side code. So deduplicating should be as simple as keeping a short-lived map of `meal-key`, `meal JSON`. Alternative you could keep a map of `meal-key`, `listener`. In both cases: if the key of the meal is already in the map, use the existing value; otherwise add a new value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. Sorry, I've edited my question and JSON to be clearer. The user has searched for all meals where tasty = true, and a subset of the meals has been returned (meals1-5). OFFER-2 contains MEAL-6 which isn't in the users originally returned results, which is why I thought it to be a bad idea to load each meal from each offer? Does that change things? Thanks!